# Browser plugin for XSD Validation of an xml document

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema-validation

What I am looking for is something similar to [this plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1108/) for FireFox 0.8 to 1.0.x. I want a plug-in that will do XSD validation against an xml document currently loaded into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does this on its own, I think. I've loaded non-validating XML docs and it told me what the error was and where (I used it at work to debug schema problems). I do, however, have the Web Developer add-on installed...so that might be providing the capability. The XML doc needs to correctly specify the namespace/schema location, of course.

The add-on you linked to appears to validate the schema itself, not an XML instance document against a schema, which is a separate process. I don't think FF will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extension you pointed would work in recent versions of Firefox. Try to download the extension, change the `maxVersion` in its manifest and install it in Firefox.

Comment: This question was already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422491/how-can-i-validate-xml-on-firefox